# About an electrostatics integral and a delta-function kernel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, integration

I'm having trouble with an integral and I would like some pointers on how to "take" it:

$$
\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{3\gamma a^{2}d^{3}\mathbf r}{4 \pi \left( r^{2} + \frac{\gamma^{2}}{c^{2}}(\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf u)^{2} + a^{2}\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}
$$
Here $\mathbf u$, $a$ and $\gamma$ are constants, and the integrand converges to a Dirac delta $\delta(\mathbf r)$ as $a\rightarrow 0$. The integral must be equal to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First choose a direction for u, along the z-axis. Then the integral is

$$ I = \int {1\over (x^2 + y^2 + A z^2 + B)^{5/2} } dx dy dz $$

Rescale z by $\sqrt{A}$ to get rid of A and restore rotational invariance.

$$ I = {1\over \sqrt{A}} \int {1\over (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + B)^{2.5}} dx dy dz $$

Now you do find the B dependence immediately from rescaling x y and z by $\sqrt{B}$ (or from dimensional analysis-- B has units length squared):

$$ I = {1\over \sqrt{A} B} \int {1\over (r^2 + 1)^{2.5}} d^3r $$

The only thing undetermined is the transcendental factor, which is just a number. You evaluate it by doing it radially and doing a string of substitutions:

$$ \sqrt{A}B I = 4\pi \int_0^{\infty} {r^2\over (r^2 +1)^{2.5} } dr $$

first $u=r^2 + 1$ gives

$$ \sqrt{A}B I = 2\pi \int_1^\infty {\sqrt{u-1}\over (u)^{2.5}} du $$

Then $v = {1\over u}$ makes it,

$$ \sqrt{A}B I = 2\pi \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-v} dv = {4\pi\over 3} $$

So

$$ I = {4\pi \over 3 \sqrt{A}B} $$

Comment: Thank you! 
The integral is equal to one:
$$
u = r^{2} + 1 \Rightarrow r = \sqrt{u - 1}.
$$

Comment: Yes, that is probably cleaner.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: It is not just cleaner, your way doesn't work--- the spherical integration will probably not produce a function with elementary antiderivative without the rescaling of z step.

Comment: Mathematica has no problems doing the integration. I can follow the steps for the $\theta$ integration and though I haven't tried doing the $r$ integral the antiderivative is complicated but elementary.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I am surprised--- the angular integration without rescaling of Z leads to complicated square roots in the denominator, and I don't see why the antiderivative should exist. Did you try getting an antiderivative for the r-integral using mathematica, or just doing the integral over both theta and r? Mathematica will do a definite integral using hypergeometric functions in intermediate steps, and then reduce with hypergeometric special values and identities, so it isn't clear that the antiderivative is elementary from the fact that Mathematica gets the right answer.

Comment: @RonMaimon see edit in my answer.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set the $z$ axis along the direction of $\mathbf{u}$ and use spherical coordinates, which reduces your integral to something like
$$\int_0^\infty dr\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\frac{r^2 \sin(\theta)}{\left(a^2 +r^2(1+\frac{\gamma^2}{c^2}\cos^2(\theta))\right)^{5/2}}.$$
Do the $\phi$ integral first and then the $\theta$ integral, transforming to $u=\cos(\theta)$. Be careful to use absolute values for the roots when necessary. After that the $r$ integral should be tough but doable.

---

EDIT to take some discussion off comments.
I gave

> Integrate[Sin[[Theta]]/(a^2+r^2 (1+[Gamma]^2 Cos[[Theta]]^2))^(5/2),[Theta]]/.[Theta]->[Pi]

to Mathematica to get
$$\frac{3 \left(a^2+r^2\right)+2 r^2 \gamma ^2}{3 \left(a^2+r^2\right)^2 \left(a^2+r^2+r^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}},$$
and then doing the radial integration by

> Integrate[r^2 (3 (a^2+r^2)+2 r^2 [Gamma]^2)/(3 (a^2+r^2)^2 (a^2+r^2+r^2 [Gamma]^2)^(3/2)),r]

gives 
$$\frac{r^3}{3 a^2 \left(a^2+r^2\right) \sqrt{a^2+r^2 \left(1+\gamma ^2\right)}}$$
for the antiderivative. I agree that the roots make one suspect nonelementary antiderivatives but it is only one root so that elliptic integrals are out. Once one has the antiderivative, of course, it is routine to check that it does differentiate to what it should.

Comment: Thank you.
But after some replacements I obtained 
$$
\frac{c}{\gamma u r (a^{2} + r^{2})^{2}}\int \frac{dt}{(1 + t^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}},
$$
where
$$
t = \frac{tru\gamma}{c\sqrt{a^{2} + r^{2}}}.
$$
But after integration I got zero. Can you tell me where I made the mistake?

Comment: For one, you're probably integrating $t$ from $-\infty$ where you should be integrating from $r=0$. Secondly, you can't factor out the $r$-dependent term from the integral!

Comment: Excuse me. I meaned
$$
t = \frac{rv \gamma u}{c\sqrt{a^{2} + r^{2}}},
$$
where 
$$
v = cos (\theta ).
$$

Comment: is this the $r$ integral or the $\theta$ integral you're trying to do?

Comment: If you're doing the $\theta$ integral then you're on the right track, but you need to be careful with the limits of integration. Setting $t=\tan(\eta)$ should reduce the integral to doable trigonometric integrals. But watch the limits of integration and watch the integrand's parity!

Comment: Yes, I meaned theta-integral.
After integration I got 
$$
\frac{1}{12}(3 sin(\varepsilon) +sin(3 \varepsilon)).
$$
After substituting frame integration I got values like
$$
sin \left(\frac{3r\gamma u}{c \sqrt(a^2 + r^2)}\right).
$$
What can I do with it? To continue integrating? Or I made a mistake?

Comment: don't use $\sin(3\epsilon)$ but rather stick to $\sin(\epsilon)$. After that use the identities $\sin(\epsilon)=t/\sqrt{1+t^2}$ and $\cos(\epsilon)=1/\sqrt{1+t^2}$. (Think triangles!)

Comment: So, you recommended to reduce the factor 3 by the equality
$$
sin(3 \varepsilon ) = 3 sin(\varepsilon ) - 4sin^{3}(\varepsilon ),
$$
and after that use equals
$$
sin(arctg(t)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + ctg^{2}(arctg(t))}} = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^{2} + 1}}?
$$

Comment: This is not the right way.

Comment: But what is the right way?

Comment: You look on the right track to me. After the angular integration you should be left with something of the form $$\int_0^\infty\frac{r^2 \left(3 a^2+r^2 \left(3+2 \gamma ^2\right)\right)}{3 \left(a^2+r^2\right)^2 \left(a^2+r^2 \left(1+\gamma ^2\right)\right)^{3/2}}dr$$